# Remove Footer When Focused on Textbox Not Working?

Tags: jquery, html

all i'm trying to do here is remove my footer when either of my textboxes have focus. I'm using jquery to attempt to do this. So at the moment I have two textboxes the first works perfectly. Now the second textbox doesn't do either when focused or unfocused. Anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

**Textbox 1 HTML**

```
<div id="inputAreaTextbox">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" name="username" class="tbinputArea" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

**Textbox 2 HTML**

```
<div id="inputAreaTextbox">
    <input type="password" id="textbox" name="password" class="tbinputArea" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

**Footer HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
    <p>&copy; 2018 SulmaxCP. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script src="JAVASCRIPT/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "#textbox" ).focus(function() {
        $("#footer").hide();
    });

    $( "#textbox" ).focusout(function() {
        $("#footer").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use `class` instead of `id`

Comment: where is this script getting called? before the HTML / after ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `#id` selector [docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. **If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM**. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

So in your jquery code Use class `tbinputArea` instead of id `textbox` :

```js
$(".tbinputArea").focus(function() {
  $("#footer").hide();
});

$(".tbinputArea").focusout(function() {
  $("#footer").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="inputAreaTextbox">
  <input type="text" id="textbox" name="username" class="tbinputArea" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div id="inputAreaTextbox">
  <input type="password" id="textbox" name="password" class="tbinputArea" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <p>&copy; 2018 SulmaxCP. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Id attribute is unique, 2 elements shall not have the same id. You can use the class as follows:

```
$(".tbinputArea").focus(function() {
  $("#footer").hide();
}).focusout(function() {
  $("#footer").show();
});
```

Rename the Ids:

```
<div id="inputAreaTextbox">
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" name="username" class="tbinputArea" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div id="inputAreaTextbox">
    <input type="password" id="textbox2" name="password" class="tbinputArea" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```